# generic types and inheritance confusion

Tags: c#, inheritance, generic-method

I have a class hierarchy like the following:

```
public class Country : MainObj
public class MainObj : BaseEntity
```

and I have business logic classes like the following:

```
public class CountryBLL<TEntity> : CountryDLL<TEntity>,IBaseBLL<TEntity> where TEntity : Country
public class MainObjBLL<TEntity> : MainObjDLL<TEntity>, IBaseBLL<TEntity> where TEntity : MainObj
```

Now the thing I want to implement is a function in that I decide which class and bll should I get for this I added IBaseBLL interfaces for return type of my function

My function is the following:

```
    public static IBaseBLL<T> GetProperBllFromObjName<T>(string entityName)
    { 
        IBaseBLL<T> baseBLL = null;
        switch (entityName)
        { 
            case "Country":
                CountryBLL<Country> aa = new CountryBLL<Country>(); 
                baseBLL = (IBaseBLL<T>) aa; //error line
                break;
        }


        return baseBLL;
    }
```

when I call the function like this:

```
IBaseBLL<BaseEntity> mainBll = GetProperBllFromObjName("Country");
```

But I am unable to cast exception in line where i added comment "error line"

so what should i do in this case. The only thing i want is writing a function to decide which bll should i use.  (i dont want to change bll declerations).

Comment: @FyodorX: This is a C# question, not a Java question.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I changed the tag to C#; good call

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: Oops! Sorry, I should try sleeping once in a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `out` to the definition of `IBaseBLL<T>` like this: `<out T>` it will probably work (can't see the rest of your code to make sure there isn't something else), unless you have methods on `IBaseBLL<T>` that have `T` as an input parameter - that would certainly break it (as it won't even compile).

The following works, but if you take out the `out` keyword you'll get the exception:

```
namespace MyProgram
{
    public class BaseEntity {}    
    public class CountryDLL<TEntity> {}    
    public class MainObjDLL<TEntity> {}    
    public interface IBaseBLL<out TEntity> {}    
    public class MainObj: BaseEntity {}    
    public class Country : MainObj {}    
    public class CountryBLL<TEntity> : CountryDLL<TEntity>,IBaseBLL<TEntity> where TEntity : Country {}    
    public class MainObjBLL<TEntity> : MainObjDLL<TEntity>, IBaseBLL<TEntity> where TEntity : MainObj {}    

    class Program
    {    
        public static IBaseBLL<T> GetProperBllFromObjName<T>(string entityName)
        { 
            IBaseBLL<T> baseBLL = null;
            switch (entityName)
            { 
                case "Country":
                    CountryBLL<Country> aa = new CountryBLL<Country>(); 
                    baseBLL = (IBaseBLL<T>) aa; //error line
                    break;
            }

            return baseBLL;
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            IBaseBLL<Country> c = GetProperBllFromObjName<Country>("Country");
            IBaseBLL<BaseEntity> d = GetProperBllFromObjName<BaseEntity>("Country");
        }
    }
}
```

Using `out` and its partner, `in`, is called [contravariance and covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx) in C#.

There's plenty of other material on it online.  I'd suggest reading about it.

One thing I haven't read that I know is how to remember the difference - it's pretty easy imho.  If all your methods return `T` then you can add `out` (think of a collection and returning items in the collection - they come *out* of the collection).  If all your methods accept `T` then you can add `in` (again, collection - you can add things and they go *in* the collection).  However if you have methods that do both you cannot add either keyword to the generic type parameter.  Also once you choose a keyword and code against it or release it you're suck; you can always add it later and be okay, but once you've chosen one you're stuck with it.

Comment: what if i want to call d.Select() function. there is a select function in MainObjDLL class but there is no select function in IBaseBLL and i cant add select function since it wants to remove "out". To call this method is there any way except for reflection?